# Insert same values into table with a different values from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert the same value into all rows except for a different value being imported from another table. I am doing it on oracle database

I have tried the following :

```
insert into table 
  (ID, version, other_id, value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9)
VALUES 
((select MAX(ID)+1 from table), '0', '5', '0', '1', 
  select name from table2, 
  select name from table2, '11', '14', '50');
```

all the values are the same except for the name from table2 will be different in each entry.

Any hint on how to insert all of them at once instead of having to do each one seprate?

Comment: Sure will. Thanks for heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, certainly, but not the way you put it (as you already know).

I'd suggest you NOT to use `max + 1` because it just won't work properly, especially in a multi-user environment. Use a sequence instead.

Here's an example: insert into `t1` values based on `t2`.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> DESC t1;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 VERSION                                            NUMBER
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> DESC t2;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT * FROM t2;

        ID JOB
---------- ----------
         1 CLERK
         2 MANAGER

SQL>
```

A sequence:

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seqt;

Sequence created.
```

Insert statement:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO t1 (id, version, job)
  2     SELECT seqt.NEXTVAL, '0', t2.job FROM t2;

2 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t1;

        ID    VERSION JOB
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0 CLERK
         2          0 MANAGER

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but everytime I run this I get an error stating that a comma is missing.

Not sure where should I place a comma since all commas are in place.

Comment: As you can see, nothing is missing in my example. I suggest you follow it **literally**. Besides, it is difficult to debug code you can't see. How is anyone supposed to assist if we don't see your code? If you still can't make it work, edit the original message and copy/paste code you used, exactly like I did.

Comment: Sorry I was missing a comma somewhere on the query. You made my day. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

my first attempt would be to generate the insert statements using concatenate; and for ID, use max_id + rownumber;

how many rows does table2 have? if not millions, concatenate should be easy approach.

Comment: Thanks but @Littlefoot answer did the trick.